# JQuery phone validation not working(fails to detect numbers)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

As the title suggests my JQuery email validation form is working well except the phone number validation.
Even i input numbers in it, it's not working. It fails to detect the numbers.
Any help will be appreciated, thanks!!

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <style type="text/css">
        #validationForm{
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: 500px;
        }

        #validationForm input{
            width:250px;
            border-radius: 20px;
            height: 30px;
            padding: 7px;
            border: 1px solid gray;
        }

        #validationForm input{
            margin-bottom:10px;
        }

        #validationForm label{
            float:left;
            font-family: helvetica;
            width: 150px;
            padding: 7px;
        }

        #confirm{
            margin-left: 165px;
            width: 100px;
            height: 30px;
        }

        #error{
            color: red;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }


    </style>

        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="error"></div>
                <form id="validationForm">
                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                    <input name="email" id="email"/>

                    <label for="telephone">Telephone</label>
                    <input name="phone" type="text"/>

                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                    <input name="password" type="password" id="pass1"/>

                    <label for="password">Confirm password</label>
                    <input name="password" type="password" id="pass2"/>

                    <input type="submit" value="Confirm" id="confirm">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $("#validationForm").submit(function(event){
        var errorMessage = "";
        event.preventDefault();
        //Email validation regex
        function isValidEmailAddress(emailAddress) {
            var pattern = new RegExp(/^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i);
            return pattern.test(emailAddress);
        };

    if(!isValidEmailAddress($("#email").val())){
        errorMessage = "<br />Please enter a valid email address";
    }

    if(!$.isNumeric($("#phone").val())){
        errorMessage = errorMessage + "<br />Please enter a valid phone number";
    }

    if($("#pass1").val() != $("#pass2").val()){
        errorMessage = errorMessage + "<br />Please enter a matching password";
    }

    if(errorMessage == ""){
        alert("success!!");
    }
    else {
    $("#error").html(errorMessage);
    }
});

    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Add id to phone field, and it should work. P.S. right now, you only have 'name' attribute there....

Comment: Thanks man, i appreciate it!! It works well now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the id="phone" :

```html
<input name="phone" type="text" id="phone"/>
```